# better way to create a method that restrict user to pass only an enum of one kind

Tags: java, enums

I have is an interface which is meant only to be overridden by enums -

```
interface Parent{
    int someMethod(); 
}
```

and method in which I am going to pass an implementor of Parent. this method wants to restrict users to pass any other implementor other than enum -

```
public static <T extends Enum<? extends Parent>> T fromInt(Class<T> enumClass){}
```

Now the issue is

1. the enum signature is unclean plus using `?`.
2. In order to access `someMethod` of parent class will need to be type casted in the method. If we like to access it like this -

   ```
   Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants())
               .filter(ev -> ((Parent)ev).someMethod() == someVal)
               .findFirst().get();
   ```

Is there a better way of creating signature of this method to solve these issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force implementors of an interface to only be enums.

However, you can achieve what you want by saying that the type `T` should be an enum type, with `T extends Enum<T>`, and a `Parent` type, with `& Parent`. `&` is used to declare an intersection of multiple interfaces. It makes sure that in the method, `T` can be bound to `Enum` and `Parent`.

This would be an implementation:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & Parent> T fromInt(Class<T> enumClass) {
    return Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants())
                 .filter(ev -> ev.someMethod() == 1)
                 .findFirst()
                 .get();
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a ***union** of two interfaces* as the class must uimplement **both** interfaces?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It is called an intersection. Take a look at the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9).

Comment: Ah! I stand corrected. Very confusing choice of words in the TLS. :(